# Invalid Keystore Format - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, keytool

I have generated a keystore by following the flutter documentation with the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Unfortunately I believe that my Flutter uses a different Java location in order to verify the key and I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/home/<username>/Documents/github/keystores/upload-keystore.jks": Invalid keystore format
```

The `flutter doctor -v` returns the following:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.4.0-91-generic, locale
    en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /home/<username>/Documents/github/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (3 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/<username>/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/<username>/Android/Sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/<username>/Android/Sdk/
    • Java binary at: /home/<username>/Documents/github/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/115/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 63.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 203.8452
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /home/<username>/Documents/github/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = /home/<username>/Documents/github/android-studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.32.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93
```

an `which keytool` returns:

```
/usr/bin/keytool
```

I believe I might have to change the Java path used by Flutter but have no idea how to o it an if it is even remotely what I nee to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a keytool generation problem. As expected my app key was generated with a different keytool installed on my machine. I had to generate the key with the right keytool again and request Google to change it.

Comment: Yes, need to use `keytool` from android-studio folder